# Are line breaks in IE's javascript always \r\n?

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

If I get an element that has a `<BR \>` inside, and get it's text with the `innerText` property, I'm seeing that the line break is two characters: 13 and 10. What determines this? Is it the browser or the web page's encoding?

I want to either make sure line breaks are always going to be this two characters (as long as it's part of the static content of the web page and not dynamically created content) or modify my text processing algorithm to handle both possibilities.

This is something I'll be using to split text into lines with the `split` method. I'm not sure if I should use `split("\r\n")` or some more complicated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your editor and/or OS. Windows uses \r(13)\n(10). Unix systems use only \n. Old macs used \r. 
You could just replace all \r\n by \n and than split on \n. So

```
//"test\r\nnewline".replace('\r\n','\n').split('\n')//only replaces the first newline
"test\r\nnewline".replace(/\r\n/g, '\n').split('\n')
```

Comment: Yea I figured this would be the simplest way to do it.

Comment: This will not work.  `.replace('\r\n', '\n')` only replaces the first `\r\n` in the string.  Even if only normalizing CRLF works for you, you need to use a regexp `.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n')`.

Comment: Good catch. Edited the answer accordingly. I feel rather stupid now :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
split(/\r\n?|\n/g)
```

should handle UNIX newlines, windows newlines, and old-style Mac newlines.

There are a few other characters that are considered newlines by [unicode](http://unicode.org/reports/tr13/tr13-9.html#Definitions) but those extra ones are unlikely to be used to replace `<br>`s in HTML `innerText`.

The 13 corresponds to `\r` which is known as CR or carriage return.
The 10 corresponds to `\n` which is known as LF or line-feed.
The combination of the two "\r\n" is known as a CRLF line separator.

Some of them are considered line terminators in other web languages.  E.g. U+2028 and U+2029 are line terminators in JavaScript and U+000C is considered a line terminator in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally dependent on OS. Windows is \r\n, \r for Mac and \n for Linux

Answer (score 0):

text.split(/\s*\n+/)

splits text on newlines.
It is always safe to remove **any** whitespace characters before a newline,
but not after.